# Qt and C++: Add QLineEdit to QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, tabwidget

I want to add a `QLineEdit` to a `QTabWidget` but I always get a

> Segmentation fault, SIGSEGV

I did it the following way:

```
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
QWidget *Tab = new QWidget(ui->tabWidget);
ui->tabWidget->addTab(Tab, "Tab1");
Tab->setLayout(layout);

QLineEdit *lE = new QLineEdit();
lE->setObjectName("Text");
lE->setText("Hello");
ui->tabWidget->widget(0)->layout()->addWidget(lE);
```

This way works for adding a `QPushButton` but somehow it doesn't work for a `QLineEdit`.

Comment: both button and line Edit are widgets, so the problem is not what you are inserting but how are you inserting it...

Comment: Try `layout->addWidget(lE);`. Maybe, the `ui->tabWidget->widget(0)` isn't the widget, you just added by `ui->tabWidget->addTab(Tab, "Tab1");` and `ui->tabWidget->widget(0)->layout()` returns a `nullptr`. (It might be another widget which just has not a layout.)

Comment: @Scheff this works, but what do I have to do, when I have more than one Tab? Can't you adress them over `ui->tabWidget->widget(Index)`?

Comment: Yes, you can address the tab widgets with [QTabWidget::widget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#widget). In (the code of) your question, you just used the wrong index. The [QTabWidget::addTab()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#addTab) returns the index of added tab for a reason. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a widget to a cell

example:

```
//
QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget();
QLineEdit* foo = new QLineEdit(this);
foo->setText("Edit");
QHBoxLayout* pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pWidget);
pLayout->addWidget(foo);
pLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
pLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
pWidget->setLayout(pLayout);

this->ui->myTable->setCellWidget(1, 1, pWidget);
```